# Semicolon delimiter inside quotes

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I want to read the csv file using CsvHelper. Delimiter has three characters ";"
Still getting BadDataException.

Code sample:

```
using var textReader = new StringReader("AA\";\"BB\";\"\n"); 
using var csvReader = new CsvReader(textReader, config);
csvReader.Read();
```

Comment: You should also show your `config`.

Comment: Also `using var ...` doesn't look like valid C# code to me.

Comment: @Filburt - that is [c# 8 syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: That's not CSV. in CSV quotes are metacharacters, you need to escape them or construct correct CSV like `"A","B"`

Comment: Have you set `config.Delimiter` to `";"` ? In the latest versions you also need to set `Mode` to `CsvMode.NoEscape` as well

Answer (score 2):

According to the sample from the comment you mentioned,

You are reading a CSV string like this which is invalid

```
I";"FH";"10222";"000001022220210505.010243";"wxt";"20210505";"";"20210505";"20210505";"170000";"01.02.43";"";"
```

Do a pre process before passing to CsvReader

```
var csv = "Substitute data from csv file here";
csv = "\"" + csv;
csv = csv.Substring(0, csv.Length - 2);
var textReader = new StringReader(csv); 
var csvReader = new CsvReader(textReader, config);
csvReader.Read();
```

This will give you

```
"I";"FH";"10222";"000001022220210505.010243";"wxt";"20210505";"";"20210505";"20210505";"170000";"01.02.43";""
```

Comment: The problem is that we receive the reports from the external service that we cannot control. Data is in the file with the csv extension but they are separeted using ";". Please find the sample row: I";"FH";"     10222";"000001022220210505.010243";"wxt";"20210505";"";"20210505";"20210505";"170000";"01.02.43";"";"

Comment: Modified the answer based on your comment

Comment: Be careful trying to use `CsvReader` on text that isn't CSV; the CSV format is [more complicated than you realize](https://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble); it isn't just arbitrary text with magic strings separating records. For example, how would @macfly represent a quote character? `";""";"`? Your code isn't going to work on that. His text isn't CSV and trying to use a CSV parser on that is going to cause nothing but grief.

Comment: Quotes are represented as meta characters in CSV and comes with escapes. This will work only if his CSV holds quotes in (\")

Answer (score 2):

Using the sample row from your comments, this appears to work.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = "\";\"",
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
        Mode = CsvMode.NoEscape
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("I\";\"FH\";\" 10222\";\"000001022220210505.010243\";\"wxt\";\"20210505\";\"\";\"20210505\";\"20210505\";\"170000\";\"01.02.43\";\"\";\""))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().Dump();
    }
}
```